# Random number between -5 and 5

Tags: java, random

Im trying to get random number between -5 and 5. Im using this code:

```
random.nextInt(10)-5;
```

but it doesnt give me number `5` and if i use `random.nextInt(10)-4;` then I never get `-5`.

So how can I get random between -5 and 5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
random.nextInt(11) - 5
```

You have 11 integers in the interval so you need 11 different values.

Answer (score 6):

The end of the range is *exclusive* in [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), so you have to use:

```
random.nextInt(11) - 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try something like

```
random.nextint(11)-5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want number between -5 and 5 inclusive you can try

```
random.nextInt(11)-5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nextInt(11)-5;
this is because there are 11 different numbers between -5 and +5.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful link apart from effective answers : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()